# Want to get day of a week as a string, But giving wrong day

Tags: java, date

I tried to get the day as a string by using the following code. But it returns wrong string. Can I fix it with this code.

```
private String getDayOfWeek(int value){
    String day = "";
    switch(value){
    case 1:
        day="Sunday";
        break;
    case 2:
        day="Monday";
        break;
    case 3:
        day="Tuesday";
        break;
    case 4:
        day="Wednesday";
        break;
    case 5:
        day="Thursday";
        break;
    case 6:
        day="Friday";
        break;
    case 7:
        day="Saturday";
        break;
    }
    return day;
```

I implements it as

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();    
String dayOfWeek = getDayOfWeek(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
System.out.println(dayOfWeek);
```

Comment: What value are you passing as an argument?

Comment: And what's wrong with `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK`?

Comment: You realize `return [-1, "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday"...][value]` works just as well instead of that huge `switch`?

Comment: @mike That's what's wrong with it...

Comment: `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` = 7. What do you expect ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK

Comment: @Doorknob That's a good idea. I'd just use `value - 1` and avoid the `null`.

Comment: @arshajii In this case `value - 1` would be the same as `-1` anyway. Good point, I'll edit my old comment

Comment: Tip: Rather than pass around a mere ambiguous integer number for day-of-week, pass around one of the `DayOfWeek` enum  objects such as `DayOfWeek.MONDAY`. This provides type-safety, ensures valid values, makes your code more self-documenting, and reduces the cognitive load of the reader. See a modern solution using this enum in the [Answer by Kuchi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52074651/642706).

Comment: @tckmn That would at least have to be `new String[] { null, "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday"… }[value]`. But the names of the days of the week are built in, we should not hard-code them outselves. Use for example [`DayOfWeek.getDisplayName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getDisplayName(java.time.format.TextStyle,java.util.Locale)).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use

```
String dayOfWeek = getDayOfWeek(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
```

What you were doing before

```
String dayOfWeek = getDayOfWeek(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

is calling your method with a random constant ([that happens to be 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882420/want-to-get-day-of-a-week-as-a-string-but-giving-wrong-day/18882471?noredirect=1#comment27868970_18882471)) the `Calendar` class is using to represent the `DAY_OF_WEEK` field in a date.

What you are actually looking for is getting the value of the day of the week in your `Calendar` instance, which is what [`Calendar#get(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29)

```
c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
```

returns.

---

On a related note, try to learn and use an actual debugger as stated in the comments.

Comment: +1 If you look at the `Calendar` source, you will see `public final static int DAY_OF_WEEK = 7;`.

Comment: +1 *"On a related note, try to log the values passed as arguments to your methods. It helps to debug."* Better idea: Use a ***debugger***. *Please*, could we leave `printf`-style debugging in the 1970s where it belongs.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you got it.

Comment: The terrible `Calendar` class was supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes. See the modern solution in the [Answer by Kuchi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52074651/642706).

Answer (score 15):

use getdisplayname method from calender object.

```
Calendar currentDate=new GregorianCalendar();

String dayOfWeek = currentDate.getDisplayName( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK ,Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
```

Answer (score 12):

I think that the best way to get the day of week is with this simple snippet of code:

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE");
String dayOfWeek = dateFormat.format(date);
System.out.println(dayOfWeek);
```

If you want to use Calendar:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE");
String dayOfWeek = dateFormat.format(c.getTime());
System.out.println(dayOfWeek);
```

The format "EEEEE" return the day of week: Sunday, Monday .. in the language of the machine, that is better that fix in English on the code.

[UPDATED]

With Java 8+ and introducing java.time package, you can achieve this with:

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = LocalDateTime.now().getDayOfWeek();
    System.out.println(dayOfWeek.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.US));
  }
}
```

In your desired Locale, also selecting TextStyle:

- FULL: Friday
- SHORT: Fri
- NARROW: F

Comment: In my case it seems 5 "E" chars only gives me the first letter of the day.  For me, I had to use this `new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");` .. notice only 4 "E" chars, to get the full word *Saturday*.  This got me going in the right direction tho .. thanks!

Answer (score 9):

## `DayOfWeek::getDisplayName`

There is a nice way of doing this with the DateTime API since Java 8

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("2018-08-29");
DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = localDate.getDayOfWeek();
String displayName = dayOfWeek.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Now `displayName` equals `Wednesday`.

With `DayOfWeek.of(int dayOfWeek)` there is no need for a switch statement.

### By number

To access the `DayOfWeek` by number as seen in the Question, use 1-7 for Monday-Sunday, per the ISO 8601 standard.

```
DayOfWeek.of( 1 ).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH)
```

> Monday

### By constant

Or use one of the seven named enum objects.

```
DayOfWeek.MONDAY.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH)
```

> Monday

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `SimpleDateFormat` for this:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
System.out.println(formatter.format(new Date());
```

This will return the String representation of the current day of the week.

Answer (score 3):

You can use below method to get Day of the Week by passing a specific date,

**Here for the set method of Calendar class, Tricky part is the index for the month parameter will starts from 0**.

```
public static String getDay(int day, int month, int year) {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        if(month==1){
            cal.set(year,0,day);
        }else{
            cal.set(year,month-1,day);
        }

        int dow = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        switch (dow) {
        case 1:
            return "SUNDAY";
        case 2:
            return "MONDAY";
        case 3:
            return "TUESDAY";
        case 4:
            return "WEDNESDAY";
        case 5:
            return "THURSDAY";
        case 6:
            return "FRIDAY";
        case 7:
            return "SATURDAY";
        default:
            System.out.println("GO To Hell....");
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Your IF in the beginning is unnecessary, you need only subtract 1 for the month in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

**Below is the two line of snippet using Java 1.8 Time API.**

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of(Integer.valueOf(year),Integer.valueOf(month),Integer.valueOf(day));
String dayOfWeek = String.valueOf(localDate.getDayOfWeek());
```

Comment: This Answer is correct but could use some discussion/explanation as Stack Overflow is meant to be more than a snippet library.

Comment: Thanks Basil for your encouragement, I will try to specify expansive in future.

Answer (score 0):

Another brute force way is

```
List<String> days = Arrays.asList( new String[] {"sunday","monday", "tuesday", "wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday"});
```

And you can use it as `days.get( <your input value> )`;

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? And a minor point, in English (opposite of many other languages) the days of the week are usually written with an uppercase letter, so `Sunday`  rather than `sunday`, etc.