# Replace integer in String in android

Tags: java, android

I have a code of integer length, content number id of days week use Fragment id example `forecast_0`... `forecast_5`. I am trying to replace the integer in String.

my code

```
for (int day = 0; day < forecast.length; day++) 
{
    if (day >= 5) {
        break;
    }

    Condition currentCondition = forecast[day];

    int viewId = getResources().getIdentifier("forecast_" + day, "id", getPackageName());
    WeatherConditionFragment fragment = (WeatherConditionFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(viewId);

    if (fragment != null) {
        fragment.loadForecast(currentCondition, channel.getUnits());
    }
}
```

I want to replace the int with string, use like

```
for (int day = 0; day < forecast.length; day++) {
    if (day >= 5&&"Thu") {
        break;
    }
}
```

I know doing wrong but i want something close to what I want if possible.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do? your question needs more clearity.

Comment: use `switch case:` for numbers one to seven and store corresponding day in a string.

Comment: @MehranZamani any example ?

Comment: Do u want to convert number of days to Mon, Tue, Wed?

Comment: @YashikaK yes this i want

Comment: @aligassan something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882420/want-to-get-day-of-a-week-as-a-string-but-giving-wrong-day).

Answer (score 0):

Use an array to read the String value.

```
String[] days = {"Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"};

if(day >= 5 && days[day - 1].equals("Thu")){

}
```

Comment: your code his work , but if i change the days of week to another lang not working