# What's the difference between Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) and Calander.DAY_OF_WEEK in java

Tags: java, kotlin, calendar, java.util.calendar

I'm new to Kotlin and while doing a course there was a bit where you worked with the current weekday.

The course used this java code to get it:

`import java.util.*`

`Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`

but I don't understand why
`Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` wouldn't work either, or whats the difference between the two.
Thanks for the explanation

Comment: I'm not sure what you're confused about in particular. `DAY_OF_WEEK` is [an `int` constant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) (a "field number", indicating which piece of data you want to retrieve). [`Calendar.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get(int)) _is_ how you get the value of a specific field, but obviously you must specify _which_ field you want (which in this case is `DAY_OF_WEEK`). You can't do anything with `DAY_OF_WEEK` itself; it's just an `int` with the value 7, not an accessor.

Comment: Internally the calendar uses an array to store the value of fields like the year, the month, etc. `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` is just a constant index to this array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Want to get day of a week as a string, But giving wrong day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882420/want-to-get-day-of-a-week-as-a-string-but-giving-wrong-day). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49539049/cant-add-days-to-calendar), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52004781/calendar-month-and-year-broke) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54708960/someone-please-explain-how-calendar-getcal-day-of-week-gives-correct-output-wh)?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use for example `LocalDate` and `DayOfWeek`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 4):

[`Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK) is a constant number, used to access fields within the Calendar object.

`Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)` uses this constant number to read the value of the "day of week" field from the calendar.

This is somewhat unusual design. Instead of adding dozens of methods like "getDayOfWeek", "setDayOfWeek", and "addDayOfWeek" for all the calendar fields, the designers of the Calendar class added "get" "set" and "add" methods that take a numeric field identifier as the parameter.

Note that Calendar is nowadays considered a "legacy" class - for new code it's better to use the classes in the `java.time` package. The modern way to get today's day of the week is:

```
DayOfWeek dow = LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek();
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you do not use the outdated error-prone date/time API from `java.util` package. Use the [modern date/time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) from `java.time` package. Learn more about it from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek());
        System.out.println(LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek().getValue());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
SUNDAY
7
```

> Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK wouldn't work either, or whats the difference
> between the two. Thanks for the explanation

[`Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK) is a constant representing the field number for `get` and `set` indicating the day of the week.

Answer (score 1):

Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK is simply a constant to tell the Calendar API which info you'd like to request:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK

Calendar.getInstance() gives you a Calendar instance. This takes things like the current timezone and local time into account. The get() method allows you to get information using the constants above.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get(int)